# Python - deep_translator does not translate text properly

Tags: python, translation

I am trying to translate some text using `deep_translator`, but I am not getting the output that I expected.

Here's my code:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

translator = GoogleTranslator(target="irish")

text_to_translate = "Hello, how are you?"

translated_text = translator.translate(text_to_translate)

print(translated_text)
```

Here when I run the code, the output is the same and the text does not seem to get translated.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: According to readthedocs, `GoogleTranslator` should be initialized with a source language: `GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='de')`

Comment: @couka: I tried defining a source language, but the output is still the same.

Comment: Did you try any other language if it is working or not?

Comment: @YashvanderBamel Every thing else will work fine. Seems like its a bug or something

Comment: I recommend you post an issue [here](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator/issues) so the developer can take a look.

Comment: @CoolCloud: Thanks a lot! I posted my issue there and the developer helped me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this issue to the developer of `deep_translator`, and he fixed this problem.

All you need to do is update `deep_translator` to it's latest version.

In your command prompt, type:

1. `pip uninstall deep_translator`
2. `pip install deep_translator`

Answer (score 0):

**Here in the above code everything is fine . But you forgot to add 'source'.**

Modified code:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
translator = GoogleTranslator(source='en',target='german')

text_to_translate = "Hello, how are you?"

translated_text = translator.translate(text_to_translate)

print(translated_text)
```

Comment: The problem is only with `irish` it seems.

Comment: `source` is by default initialized to `auto` which means its going to auto detect the language supplied.

Comment: @CoolCloud: Yes, the problem is only with Irish and a few other languages (eg- Indonesian).